# Creating an Android background service that can be called from ADB

Tags: android, adb

I have issue getting IP address on my testing environment since my phones are connected with VPN so ping and curl not working on ADB shell. phones are not rooted.

I need to have a service I can call from adb shell that return the IP address (by calling an api req to a  https://api.ipify.org/?format=json for example) and ping google to understand if internet is working or not.

I need this service to be hidden from the rest of the apps on the system.

Where do I begin ?

Comment: Termux includes command-line tools that are implemented in Java and Termux allows to call it via a script. The execution uses `/system/bin/app_process` to execute the tool packed into an APK file. These tools also work via adb so this should be a feasible approach to implement what you need as command-line APK program.

Comment: How are you connected to the phones if you don't know the IPs? USB?

Comment: USB yes, I need public IP of internet.